# C# Windows Forms Приостановить выполнение кода до определенного действия на другой форме

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность, события

Доброго времени суток!

Итак. Есть приложение Windows Forms. И, собственно, есть 2 формы. При нажатии на кнопку в первой форме запускается выполнение некоего кода из стороннего класса.

```
Form1: form
 //
 //...
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    SomeClass se = new Someclass();
    se.Method1()
 }
```

В процессе выполнения этого кода наступает момент, когда нужно передать данные в другую форму, чтобы там их пользователь обработал (выбрал нужные параметры из набора), и вернуть результирующую выборку обратно для дальнейшей обработки.
Что происходит в методе:

```
    class Someclass
    {
       public void Method1()
       {
          //что-то обрабатывается, а затем..
          //передается в другую форму для взаимодействия с пользователем
          Form2 ch = new Form2(this, for_check);
          ch.Show();          
          ch.onClick += copyArr;
          //продолжение
       }
    }
```

где `сh`- экземпляр формы, в которую передают данные для обработки.
`ch.onClick` - событие, срабатывающее в форме, когда заканчивается вся нужная обработка. `copyArr` - функция копирования массива, вызываемая при срабатывании события.

Что происходит во второй форме:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public int[] arr;
    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    public delegate void MethodContainer(WithExcel wb, ChooseList ch);
    public event MethodContainer onClick;

    // Выполняются определенные действия, потом нужно нажать на кнопку

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        arr = new int[list.Count];
        arr = list.ToArray();        
        onClick();
        this.Close();
    }

}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что `Method1()` не дожидается срабатывания события и пытается продолжить исполнение кода. А так как заполнение массива еще не произошло, то вылезают различные `NullPointerException`-ы на незаполненный массив. 
Как можно поставить выполнение кода в `Method1()` на паузу до момента срабатывания события? Думаю стоит сказать сразу, что в потоках я еще не сильно силен, и мб упускаю что-то совсем детское.

Comment: `ch.ShowDialog();`

Comment: @Igor Спасибо. Помогло

Comment: Кажется не совсем силен я не только в потоках))